# Rails Carrierwave + Koala gem picture issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, koala-gem

`User` model has `AvatarUploader` mounted which processes avatar upload via `Devise`. And the response is fine:

```
"avatar": {
      "url": "http://185.48.228.95/uploads/user/avatar/avatar.png"
    }
```

But when User registers via Facebook (`Koala` gem) his profile picture gets processed by Carrierwave (I do not want this).

Users controller part where I set avatar for Facebook registration:

```
image = @graph.get_object("me?fields=picture.type(large)")
avatar = image['picture']['data']['url'].to_s
@user["avatar"] = avatar
```

Which works fine. Bit some why it gets processed by Carrierwave AvatarUploader and gives current response. Which is not valid URL.

```
"avatar": {
  "url": "http://185.48.228.95/uploads/user/avatar/https%3A/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/11133815_976100819074773_1891085821809120990_n.jpg%3Foh%3D3bd392a5fdb9c5f1e3e6b01b8d47a1c0%26oe%3D590010A0"
}
```

How do I make it work so it sets the correct FB avatar link?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out Carrierwave has its helper for such purposes

`@user.remote_avatar_url = image['picture']['data']['url']`